# Using chunk in job queue

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I have a quantity sync functionality that update the product quantity, I used Job to do this, but I have many issues regarding timeout.

so by question is, what is the best way to do jobs for many records

```
foreach($records as $record){
   UpdateSync::dispatch($record);
}
```

or

```
UpdateSync::dispatch($records);
```

and inside the update sync I have the loop to do the login

and whats the pros and cons of each ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use chunk for any of crud operations. Ex: if you have 1000 data in users table, you can use

```
    User::where('status', 1)->chunk(function ($chunked_users) {
        foreach ($chunked_users as $user) {
            UpdateSync::dispatch($user);
        }
    });
```